# How to calculate the volume of the following hyperboloid using integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I need to find the volume of the hyperboloid defined by the equation

> ${x^2\over30^2}+{y^2\over30^2}-{(z-160)^2)\over120^2}=1$ and bounded by the planes $z=0$ and $z=190$.

I decided to use cylindrical coordinates and wrote the next integral:

> $\int^{190}_0 \int^{2pi}_0\int^T_0 ({r} )drd\theta dz$

Where $T$ is the radius $r=\sqrt{30^2+{(z-160)^2\over120^2}}$

I don't know if I defined the integral correctly.

Comment: Yes the approach is correct but there is a mistake in value of $r$. It should be $r = \sqrt{30^2+ 30^2 \cdot {(z-160)^2\over120^2}}$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Your volume which is of revolution, is given by

$$V=\int_0^{190}S(z)dz$$
with
$$S(z)=\pi r^2(z)$$
and
$$r^2(z)=30^2(1+\frac{(z-160)^2}{120^2})$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$$\int\limits_{z = 40}^{190} \pi 30^2 \left(1 + \frac{(z - 160)^2}{120^2} \right)\ dz = \frac{34125 \pi}{2}$$

where you have to solve for the lower limit on $z$ by setting $x = y = 0$.

Comment: Your lower limit of $z$ is not correct. It should be $0$. Also $x = y = 0$ is not possible on this hyperboloid of one sheet.